# Need to route from one Html page to other page , i am using cordova and Backbone.js to create an android app

Tags: cordova, backbone.js-collections

I am using Backbone.js and cordova to create an android app. We are creating a login form and are using an ajax call to the web service. Can anyone say the what code should be written into the Success: `function(){------}` of ajax function so that it redirects to another HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to another page using window.location.href. An example is shown below

```
    function(){ window.location.href = "examplePage.html";}
```